# Quick way to group timestamps by order of week

Tags: algorithm, date

All:

I wonder if there is easy way to group timestamp by order of week, for example:

**A month usually has 5 or 4 weeks, once given a timestamp**( something like UTC time 1483465353929 which is 1/3/2017 that should be put into 1st week group, say we use the first Monday of a month as the starting of the first week of that month, and if the timestamp is early than the first Monday like 1/1/2017, it should be put into previous month's last week group which is 5th week) **How can I quickly identify its week order? Any implementation will be appreciated**

Thanks

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this problem?

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for reply. What I am thinking about is firstly figure out the first Monday of that month according to the timestamp, then see if the timestamp is earlier than it, if so, figure out previous month(in my case will be Year 2016 and Month 12) first Monday timestamp and find out how many weeks does it have, and put that stamp into last week group. if the timestamp is later than it, I will just find the first Monday timestamp and find the week order of given timestamp week order by keeping adding 7days. But I feel this way is kinda slow and a lil naive

Comment: Time stamps and dates are messy. You just have to deal with it. Note that there may be library functions that convert time stamps into fixed-format strings. That's probably a good place to start, if available in the programming language that you're using.

Comment: Start by getting the day of 01/01/2017. Do the math to compute the first Monday of the year. From there, it's simple math to compute the end of each 4-week or 5-week month.